# Getting data from data warehouse into relational database

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

This fairly unusual, but because of office politics etc. we have (read-only) access to the data warehouse, but not to the live data. However we need up-to-date data to populate our relational (OLTP) database (MS SQL server. The data in the warehouse (also MS) is in star schema format (i.e. Dimensions and Facts). I am not very familiar with warehouse DBs. How can I get data from the warehouse into a relational database? My google-fu was too weak to get me any answers (lots for the other way round).

Thanks
Chavoux

Answer (score 1):

If there is a data-warehouse, then the ETL process is already in place. So, use the same tool (SSIS ?) that loads the DW to extract data from the DW and move it to a different DB. You can probably ask your ETL guy to help too :).

Answer (score 0):

SSIS packages?  Anything that can load and transform data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the data warehouse is a SQL Server database so standard SQL can be used.  You can use SSIS to transform the data from the DW and load it to the OLTP database.